# exe not giving output in php

Tags: php, exe

I am trying to call an exe from php. the exe is created from Qt. It runs in Qt as well as from the command line but when I try to run it from php I get incomplete output. The exe takes around 5-7sec to run.

The output that I get from command line is:

```
--(!)Error loading
--(!)Error loading
1
2
3
4
5
```

I am not sure what the error loading is for but it stills run the exe and gives the output. But when I run it from php I get

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "--(!)Error loading" [1]=> string(18) "--(!)Error loading" }
```

After Error loading it takes abit time in the command line to give the output so may be the php does not wait for it to complete. I am not sure. How can I find out what the error is and how can I solve this? The php script that I am using to call the exe is:

```
<?php
   $addr="/home/ggt/project/build-test-Desktop-Release/test";
  exec($addr,$data);
  var_dump($data);

?>
```

I tried using shell_script too. But it does not work. I even inserted a sleep(20) after exec but still its the same.

Comment: Are you trying to execute a windows executable under linux?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped it no its a linux exe

Comment: can you diff the output of `strace originalcommand` between normal and under-php execution?

Comment: I tried running $ php -f try.php in the cmd it gives all the output but how come I am not getting the output in my website?

Comment: @LajosVeres it seems the output from the strace is same

Comment: I am not sure that strace will help, but sometimes can. You can redirect the output of `strace` with -o to a file. And you can check if is there any difference. But this is only an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem...It was because there was an imshow() in the code which I missed to comment out. So, it did not execute the whole program and stopped it. After I removed the imshow I was able to get all the output.