# Run Qt generated executable (EXE) through php (LINUX)

Tags: php, c++, linux, exe

Sorry, this question must be repeated, it already asked the following link, but the answer is not cleared.. So can anyone please solve this problem???

[exe not giving output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854746/exe-not-giving-output-in-php/19898296#19898296)

I am trying to call a Qt generated executable file through PHP code which fails to run the exe.. The same exe runs on double-click and through command line..

Below is my code

```
<?php
    $exec_cmd = exec('"./myEXE"');
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="RUN" onclick="$exec_cmd"/>
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

Thank You...

Comment: It's not how php works. Command is executed when server process request, not when client interact with html. You need to write js code to end request, and server-side that executes it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. It means that the php code is compiled and executed in the server and the output is sent to the client.

What you are trying to do is to use PHP as client-side language, like JavaScript.

The porgram is executed when the page is displayed and you want it to be displayed once the user clicks on the button, for that you must use JavaScript.

I would use AJAX to make the request to the server so it can execute the program but if you don't want to use javascript you can set the form to redirect the page with a GET or POST parameter and check in PHP if that parameter is set

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I am a newbie to PHP, but just wanted to mention that when I tried 'shell_exec()' to run a compiled C executable on linux and normal executable programs the code works fine... but not with the Qt executable..